# sql design prevent dual procceesing

Tags: sql, design-patterns

I have a SQL stored procedure call it "StPro", It is called by a web-service.
I want that at all times there will be no more than one "StPro" working.
So I need an idea, what can I do in "StPro" to prevent another "StPro" to start working along.
Tried having a value in a table that tells me if there is already a working "StPro", when "StPro" starts it sets the value to 1, when it ends it sets it to 0, if the value is already 1 the procedure ends without doing anything.
Problam is, if you start two "StPro"s at the same time, the value doesnt change on time to prevent the second one from starting.
Thanks

Comment: This is usually the wrong design - either you're trying to limit to one execution at a time due to other errors that are causing issues when multiple copies run, or it probably ought to be some sort of queueing system and some background job (or, say, service broker) dealing with dequeueing and the bulk of the task.

Comment: Mostly, I dont want more than one at the same time due to performence essues. But there are errors that accure because multiple copies run. I didnt mind that because it is not supposed to happen.

Comment: Table level locking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `Table(ID int)`, put `PK` on that table, and at top of your stored procedure add `insert into Table values(1)`. And at the end of proc `delete * from Table`. Add `Try Catch` block and return from proc if error occured.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am doing, problam is if you call two at the same time, it doesnt change the table fast anough to prevent the secont one to start.

Comment: It's impossible. You are updating value in table. In this example it is insert into PK. It won't be able to add twice value(1) in that table, so you are guaranted that while table has row vith value(1) you can not execute that proc

Comment: Sorry, I'm not doing exactly that. I'll try it.
Thanks